# Seek for help about Android Programming

Tags: android

I want to know how to control system resources and services like bluetooth, SMS, phone contacts etc. 
Honestly, i want to know how or what to do to control sms usage based on user behavior, block incoming call or change it to auto vibrate mode without user noticed like that. 
Actually, I want it for my assignment about context aware access control paper. 
I choose Android for implementation but i am afraid i 
couldn't submit my paper in time if i study android from the beginning and all by myself.
No offense but I want to avoid errors.
I feel my head becomes swollen whenever "force close error" show as I need it urgent.

Comment: Renegade, Hello and welcome. Everything you described can be found here: http://developer.android.com/index.html There are many examples with full source code. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As Willytete said [developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is the best one for you
There you can find

- [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
- [Download the Android SDK and start programing](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- The first program tutorial where you can start [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) where it give you a lot of ideas
- [List of Sample Apps](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html), where there is a lot of codes
- [Getting the Samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html), it explain how to use this.

You will get all the information from developer site that you needed, while move from beginner to an expert

Comment: API dun match error displays oftenly. How to correct this? And like i said above, i only have limited access to internet. So, is there any shortcut to learn faster?